# Fade out sides of div tag with image background CSS

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I'm building a site, and I have an animating image in my header. This image is a coloured bar that animates from right to left on a loop to give the impression of it infinitely moving left.

What I would like to accomplish, is to have a fade in/out effect on the left and the right side of the image, without affecting the animation of it's background image.

This is my HTML code:

```
<div id="hbaranim"><div id="hbarchild"></div></div>
```

And my current CSS (with just the animating image):

```
#hbaranim {
width: 100%;
height: 5px;
overflow-x: hidden;
padding-bottom: 10px;
padding-top: 10px;
}
#hbaranim #hbarchild {
position: relative;
width: 8524px;
height: 5px;
background-image: url("img/colorbartile.png");
background-repeat: repeat-x;   
-webkit-animation: hbaranim_roll linear 245s infinite;
}
@-webkit-keyframes hbaranim_roll {
from { right: 0px; }
to { right: 2131px; }
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ghmskuqa/2/)

Eddit: Currently using the HTML is using two div tags, but they don't have any content in them, so using just one would probably be better (not sure how to that to be honest...)

Eddit 2: Just to clarify, the animating image is positioned over a gradient background, so just putting another gradient over the image like some of you suggested won't work in this case. It really need's to be transparent at the sides.

Eddit 3: Some of you also suggested using a CSS gradient instead of an image, but the image I use on my actual site contains some other details that would be impossible to replicate in CSS. For this example I used an image that could indeed be replicated with a CSS gradient quite easily.

Eddit 4: Updated the fiddle to include the whole header

Comment: I don't see anything anymation. I added some lines of code so that it works for FF to but nothing is happening: http://jsfiddle.net/ghmskuqa/1/

Comment: @Vinc199789 It is happening. But it takes 245 seconds to finish one loop :D Change that to see it working :/

Comment: Ties, in your live code, is there any more HTML within your divs or would you be open to a solution that uses only one div?

Comment: @Shaggy One div would be fine, probably even better than my current solution. The tutorial I followed for the animation was for an animating background, but I wasn't sure how to adapt it to use just one div.

Comment: Thanks for the Fiddle but could you include the gradient that sits behind the bar as well? Also, if you can position and size the bar as it is in you live code, that would help as well.

Comment: @Shaggy Updated the fiddle to include all of the HTML for the header and all CSS applied to it

Comment: Ah. Yes, a radial gradient would make this tricky but, given that it isn't very pronounced and that the animated bar is so small, I think it would be save enough to just fade the overlays to the darker grey without the visual disparity being too apparent. Let me try it and I'll update my answer momentarily.

Answer (score 3):

You could use absolutely positioned pseudo elements on the parent element with gradient backgrounds to achieve this. You can also achieve the same effect with a single `div`.

**UPDATE:** Following on from edit 3 in the original question, the rainbow gradient I've used below can be replaced with an image file, the exact same principles apply.

- [More information on pseudo elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements)
- [More information on gradients](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_gradients)

**EXAMPLE**

```css
*{box-sizing:border:box;}
body{margin:0;}
.header{
    background:radial-gradient(ellipse at center,#242424 0%,#141414 100%);
    box-shadow:0px 0px 10px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.75);
    height:150px;
    position:relative;
}
h1{
    color:#fff;
    font-family:arial;
    font-size:48px;
    padding:25px 0 0;
    margin:0;
    text-align:center;
}
h2{
    color:#fff;
    font-family:arial;
    font-size:24px;
    line-height:25px;
    margin:0;
    text-align:center;
}
#hbaranim{
    -webkit-animation:hbaranim_roll linear 10s infinite;
    animation:hbaranim_roll linear 10s infinite;
    background:linear-gradient(90deg,#f00 0%,#ff0 16.667%,#0f0 33.333%,#0ff 50%,#00f 66.667%,#f0f 83.333%,#f00 100%) 0 0 repeat-x;
    background-size:200%;
    bottom:10px;
    height:5px;
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
}
#hbaranim::before,#hbaranim::after{
    content:"";
    display:block;
    height:100%;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    width:25%;
    z-index:1;
}
#hbaranim::before{
    background:linear-gradient(90deg,rgba(20,20,20,1),rgba(20,20,20,0));
    left:0;
}
#hbaranim::after{
    background:linear-gradient(90deg,rgba(20,20,20,0),rgba(20,20,20,1));
    right:0;
}
@-webkit-keyframes hbaranim_roll{
    0%{
        background-position:0 0;
    }
    100%{
        background-position:200% 0;
    }
}
@keyframes hbaranim_roll{
    0%{
        background-position:0 0;
    }
    100%{
        background-position:200% 0;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <h1>Name of Site</h1>
  <h2>www.site.nl</h2>
  <div id="hbaranim"></div>
</div>
```

---

If you're feeling adventurous, you can do this without the nested `div` ([Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mpujm402)) or *even* without the parent `div` ([Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mpujm402/1))

---

The following snippet was provided as an example while awaiting Ties' confirmation that removing the child `div` was an option and is included below as a matter of record.

```css
#hbaranim{
    overflow:hidden;
    padding:10px 0;
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
}
#hbaranim #hbarchild{
    background-color:#000;
    height:20px;
    position:relative;
    width:8524px;
    z-index:1;
}
#hbaranim::before,#hbaranim::after{
    content:"";
    display:block;
    height:20px;
    position:absolute;
    top:10px;
    width:20%;
    z-index:2;
}
#hbaranim::before{
    background:linear-gradient(90deg,rgba(255,255,255,1),rgba(255,255,255,0));
    left:0;
}
#hbaranim::after{
    background:linear-gradient(90deg,rgba(255,255,255,0),rgba(255,255,255,1));
    right:0;
}
```

```html
<div id="hbaranim">
    <div id="hbarchild"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I deliberately omitted the animation as it wasn't relevant to the solution (i.e., static or animated background, the solution is the same). As I see it, the better course of action here, rather then reposting the answer (albeit with credit), would have been to ask for its inclusion in my answer.

Comment: Normaly this would do the trick, but unfortunately, my image is nog on a solid collor background, but on a gradient background. So I'm looking for a way to to actually make the image transparent, and not to add a colour gradient on top of the image.

Comment: You can replace the solid bg colour above with a bg image instead, it will still work the same way. If you have a look at my second solution at the end of my answer, if, as @AndreaLigios assumes, your image is a rainbow gradient, the entire effect is achievable with a single `div` and no external image. If your image isn't a rainbow gradient, could you share it 'til we see if it can be reproduced in CSS alone?

Comment: Ah, just read your comment again and I understand what you mean. Could you maybe post a Fiddle with your imagery/gradients in place so we can see exactly what needs to be done?

Comment: As @Ties has confirmed that removing the child `div` is an option, I've updated my answer to reflect this and included my original example at the end,as a matter of record.

Comment: Answer updated to include parent element with radial gradient background and to adjust colours of overlays accordingly.

Comment: Looks like you've copied my CSS and directly applied it to your HTML. The biggest problem is you're now using a ID selector for the header, when you need to be using a class selector. I'll update the code above to use a class instead but what I've written is really only intended as a demonstration of how to achieve what you want, you'll need to edit it to suit your needs.

Comment: By the way, if you're feeling adventurous, you can do this without the nested `div`: http://jsfiddle.net/mpujm402/ or even without the parent `div`: http://jsfiddle.net/mpujm402/1/

Comment: I got it working in jsfiddle, but when I copy the code over to my site, there is no sing of a colored bar in my header, but I do see the fade in and fade out bits at about 30px above the bottom of my screen. (they seem to be fixed there, if I scrol down they don't stick to my screen) Thees do have a bit of color where they start to fade out, and from what I can see the gradient seems to be animating properly, but most of it is invisible, and it's in totaly the wrong place.

This is probably hard to diagnose with just this info, but let me know is you have any tips.

Comment: Sounds like an issue with the positioning. Double check that the values for `position` are correct in all instances.

Comment: @Ties, as it's been a couple of weeks since you last replied, I assume you have everything working. If this has answered your question to your satisfaction, maybe you could consider accepting it :)

Comment: Sorry I haven't been replying for a while, but I'v been giving this a break and focusing on other parts of the site. Unfortunately I stil haven't got a working solution, but once I do i'l post it.